# open recent option disabled in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

When I open jmeter, the load file option that is open recent file is not working.It is disabled.What should I do.I tried deleting jar files one by one in lib folder but it did not help. I am using jmeter version 4

Answer (score 6):

JMeter uses Java [Preferences](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) class to store the list of recently opened files

1. On Windows "Recent Files" are being stored under the following path in [Windows Registry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry)

   ```
   Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\JavaSoft\Prefs\org\apache\jmeter\gui\action
   ```
2. On Linux most probably it would be:

   ```
   ~/.java/.userPrefs
   ```
3. On MacOSX it should live under:

   ```
   ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.java.util.prefs
   ```

Your user must have access to this location (i.e. you may have to run JMeter as Administrator once) to get the storage created. On Linux/Unix systems the user should have read/write permissions to the given location.

If preferences don't exist or are empty - you will not be able to see anything.

---

Given you mentioned you deleted files from "lib" folder you might remove something critical by accident which may cause JMeter malfunction. So consider reinstalling JMeter from [downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page and re-installing missing plugins with dependencies using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)